# Why isn't my HTML file showing up in MVC 4 when it's in the Shared folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, hyperlink

Given this link:

```
<a href="~/Views/Shared/_Test.html">Test</a>
```

Which is an HTML page in Shared folder as shown in the href attribute. Shouldn't MVC be able to find this in the Shared folder?

When I click on the link I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and am posting for others benefit...

1. MVC routing is wired up out-of-the-box to NOT handle inbound .HTML requests.  So why fight it?
2. Create an action method that looks like this:

   ```
   public ActionResult GetHTMLFile(string filename)
   {
       var dir = "/Views/HTML/";
       var suffix = ".html";
       var path = dir + filename + suffix;

       return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
   }
   ```

This tells us that we have a Views folder and a subfolder named HTML where we store all of our HTML files and ensure the suffix is always html.  VS does this by default when you add new HTML files. This method is "building" the full path to the HTML file.  It then uses FilePathResult to return the content.

3. Use the ActionLink helper because you can easily configure the action method name as well as the controller name if you need it...

   ```
      @ActionLink("Layout File changes", "GetHTMLFile", new {filename="_Layout"})
   ```

We are "Tricking" MVC by only passing part of the file name (without the extension and without the actual path).  The controller get's the string and serves up the HTML for us.